# How to cycle through div's with javascript while keeping the div's in the same location

Tags: php, html, jquery, css

I am using php, sql, html/css, and javascript. Basically I want to only show one div at a time, which I have completed, except once the first div is hidden the next one shows up right below it. Instead I would like it show up all in the same place as you cycle through it. Any idea how I could fix this?

PHP/HTML: (obviously simplified but I don't think more is necessary)

```
foreach($headers as $header)
{

        $content .= "<div class='main_' id='card'>";
        $content .=  "</div>";
        $content .= "<button class='next'>Next Order</button>";
        echo $content;
}
```

CSS:

```
.main_{
  visibility: hidden;
}
.main_.active{
  display:block;
}
```

```
var normalDivs = [];
var focusDiv;

function loopThru(){
  focusDiv +=1;
  if (focusDiv > normalDivs.length-1){
    focusDiv = 0;
  }
  $('.main_').each(function(){
    $(this).css('visibility','hidden');
  });
  normalDivs[focusDiv].css('visibility','visible');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.main_').each(function(){
    normalDivs.push($(this));
  });
  focusDiv = 0;
  normalDivs[focusDiv].css('visibility','visible')
  $('.next').click(loopThru);
  
});
```

Comment: Use `display:none:` instead of `visibility:hidden;`?

Comment: That removes the div entirely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two options:

1. as mykaf commented - you can use `display: none;` instead of `visibility: hidden;`.

that will completely remove the div, but you can recreate it when setting the `display` back to `block`.

2. along with `visibility: hidden;` add `position: absolute;`
   that should let the visible div be in the same location as the first one.